# Strange compilation issue with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

Why does the following program compile with **gcc**, ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void foo(double x) {
   printf("%f", sin(2));
}

int main() {
   foo(1);
}
```

... while this other program doesn't?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void foo(double x) {
   printf("%f", sin(x));
}

int main() {
   foo(1);
}
```

It gives the following error message:

```
/tmp/ccVT7jlb.o: nella funzione "foo":
fun.c:(.text+0x1b): riferimento non definito a "sin"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*
```

Comment: Are you using the `-lm` option when compiling both executables?

Comment: @wolfPack88  No, I wasn't.  I thought standard libraries were automatically linked.  Now it works, thanks!

Comment: The first one doesn't actually have to link in the math library, because it can optimize `sin(2)` into a constant. The second one needs to load the `sin()` function, so you have to tell it to link to `libm` (or whatever your platform's equivalent is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link to `libm.so` like this

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror source.c -o executable -lm
```

see the `-lm`

Comment: Also make sure it's the last option.